# Implement hook_field_create_instance(), hook_field_delete_instance() and hook_field_attach_rename_bundle()

Tags: 8, entities, hooks

When creating a new field type (e.g. [address](https://www.drupal.org/project/address) or [dimension](https://www.drupal.org/project/dimension)), I am looking for the Drupal 8 equivalent of [hook_field_create_instance()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_create_instance/7.x) and [hook_field_delete_instance()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_delete_instance/7.x) that are available in Drupal 7.
The same goes for [hook_field_attach_rename_bundle()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_rename_bundle/7.x).

The hook_field_create_instance() could be used e.g. for defining default values on existing entities. Let's say define the new field default value on existing Node instances after attaching (= creating a field instance) to a Content Type.

After digging around on the parent classes and interfaces of the classes that are involved in the definition of a new field type (FieldFormatter, FieldType, FieldWidget namespaces) + [Field Types API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_types/8.2.x), I found the [PluginManagerBase::createInstance](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Component!Plugin!PluginManagerBase.php/function/PluginManagerBase%3A%3AcreateInstance/8.2.x) (and thus [FieldTypePluginManager::createInstance](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldTypePluginManager.php/function/FieldTypePluginManager%3A%3AcreateInstance/8.2.x)) but didn't found a way to define custom code for these operations.

Answer (score 1):

These two drupal resources should get you there:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2054619
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2012896

As an aside, here is how I found the changes: [Drupal Changes](https://www.drupal.org/list-changes/drupal/published?keywords_description=field_create_instance&to_branch=&version=&created_op=%3E%3D&created%5Bvalue%5D=&created%5Bmin%5D=&created%5Bmax%5D=)